# CodeIgniter Redirection with .htaccess giving error

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, .htaccess

I am facing problem with making urls of my website seo friendly. So I want to redirect all the urls below to http://example.in/

```
http://example.in/index.php
http://www.example.in/
http://www.example.in/index.php
http://www.example.in/Home
http://www.example.in/Home/
http://www.example.in/Home/index
```

My .htacces looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.in$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.in/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

and config file looks like

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.in/'; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

The problem is these 3 urls are redirecting just fine.

```
http://example.in/index.php
http://www.example.in/
http://www.example.in/index.php
```

but when checking others

```
http://www.example.in/Home
http://www.example.in/Home/
http://www.example.in/Home/index
```

they redirect to index.php? as

```
http://www.example.in/index.php?/Home
http://www.example.in/index.php?/Home/
http://www.example.in/index.php?/Home/index
```

or like this if I add the code for removing index.php

```
http://www.example.in/?/Home
http://www.example.in/?/Home/
http://www.example.in/?/Home/index
```

Why is this ?/ is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line, you're missing a '`./`' before index, and you have a '`?`' in front of index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You have to change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```